# Autocomplete plus free text in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, autocomplete

I'm editing as I haven't been able to make myself clear:

I want to have one textarea, where you will be able to send a message to a friend.

On that textarea, you type your message. Somewhere in that message, you start typing your friends name, and autocomplete should help you finish it.

Once I submit that form, i should be able to retrieve

1. full text of the message
2. id of the friend's name that was autocompleted.

So as you can see, it si very similar to the "status update" in facebook, with the exception that only one name of one friend should be addable.

I hope its clearer!

I'm using Rails 3.2, with JQuery.

Comment: I don't see your problem: You should build a normal form where just one text input is going to be the autocomplete one, and than you could add a textarea for the message. When the user clicks on submit you should get both. The values should end up in the controller in the `params` hash.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to have 2 separate fields: just one big textarea for everything. And the user should be able to type the name of the contact anywhere in the textarea field: at the beginning, in the middle or at the end if they please.

Comment: And there should be autocomplete for the username? For that you need to get busy yourself, at least I don't know any gem for that. My approach would be to write some Javascript, takes the last word and makes an ajax request with it. The controller should make a search for users starting with the string and deliver the names with ids back to the browser. Now its just to display the names and save the selected names' ids into a hidden input field. I hope you got an idea...

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are trying to do actually please ask question in detail so the community can answer you in a better way.

And you can use jquery autocomplete plugin and also there in multi auto complete plugin is

available for select multiple values by comma seperated.